# Automatic update new version of symbian application

Tags: qt, symbian, auto-update

I have a Qt Symbian application. I didn't publish it via Nokia OVI store. I'm distributing the app in my own website. What I need to know is, If I released a new version of my app, the user should be able to automatically download the new version.

I mean, whenever he/she launch the app, he should be informed about the release of the new version (if an update is available). And then he may have the option to install the update or skip it.

How to achieve this....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no automatic mechanism in Symbian for this. You could set up a web service on your web site (which can be as simple as a static txt file that you update manually as you roll out a new version of your app) that returns the latest released version number of your application. Then when you start your application it would query the web service and compare the latest released version with its own version. If the installed application is older, it can initiate the installation of the new version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll surely have a try. As you said, I can initiate the download. But once the app is downloaded, I need to automatically initiate the installation. Also the previous version app must be uninstalled. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: If you use the same vendor ID and application name in the package file (and thus in the sis) and change only the version numbers, then the system _updates_ your application: I think this is what you want. Once you have the URL of your SIS file I think it is enough to open that URL in the browser: it will recognize that it is an installation package and ask the user if he wants to install it. See also http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_launch_other_applications_in_Qt

Comment: Then the installed app will replace the older version, Am I right? Now I tried using QProcess. But it shows "Failed to Start" message only.

Comment: Then the installed app will replace the older version, Am I right? - if you do everything well, yes. Try using QDesktopServices::openUrl for opening the URL of the sis file as it is written in the wiki page in my prev. comment

Comment: Yes. I tried using QDestopServices to open the Url. It works fine and opens the link in browser. Thanks for your comments.